# Does Haskell's 'do' notation always involve a monad?

Tags: haskell

I had always figured that Haskell's `do`-notation was just sugar for monad composition (`>>=`).
Then I came across this instance of it, and am not sure what monad is in use here, or whether there even is one:

```
rollDieThreeTimes :: (Die, Die, Die)
rollDieThreeTimes = do
  let s = mkStdGen 0
      (d1, s1) = randomR (1, 6) s
      (d2, s2) = randomR (1, 6) s1
      (d3, _) = randomR (1, 6) s2
  (intToDie d1, intToDie d2, intToDie d3)

intToDie :: Int -> Die
...
```

My questions:

- Is there even a monad underlying the `do`-notation of this example?
- If not, is there some special form of `do`-notation that permits this
  format of `let`-statements with no monad?
- If there is a monad, which is it? And, how would one convert this `do`-notation into `>>=` form?

Comment: `do`-notation is 99% of the time used for Monads. It can be used for a less general form than `Monad`, like `Applicative` or `Functor`. With [`ApplicativeDo`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/applicative_do.html) the following expression `\as -> do a <- as; pure (not a)` works for any Functor: `Functor f => f Bool -> f Bool`. There are also cases where you want `do`-notation for cases that don't exactly fit the Monad/.. type classes, that's what [`QualifiedDo`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/qualified_do.html#extension-QualifiedDo) does.

Comment: There are further generalisations of `do`-notation that allow failing (`MonadFail`). The expression `\as -> do True <- as; pure ()` requires your Monad to have a notion of failure `MonadFail m => m Bool -> m ()`. If you depend on a computation before it is run you need [`RecursiveDo`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/recursive_do.html#extension-RecursiveDo). `\as bs -> mdo a <- as b; b <- bs a; pure (a, b)` requires `MonadFix` to work: `MonadFix m => (b -> m a) -> (a -> m b) -> m (a, b)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`do` *should* always be used in a monadic context. But if you only have one expression in the `do`-block, then it desugars to just that expression, so there are no references to `>>=`, and no Monad constraint arises.

So you can write

```
do let x = a
       y = b
   foo
```

which is equivalent to

```
let x = a
    y = b
in foo
```

but really, you should just write the latter.

I haven't read HPFFP, which Google tells me is probably the book you got this example from. It comes from the chapter on State, and it seems like the author(s) introduce this as a simple state-less example, then later add state to it. Perhaps they chose this unusual construction for pedagogical reasons, for example to keep it similar to a later version using monadic binds in place of the let bindings.

Comment: Single-statement `do` can be used for avoiding parentheses, because it's a syntactic herald. For example `2 * do 4+5` evaluates to 18. Now, _is it a good idea_? Certainly not in that example, but for bigger expressions it can actually make sense. I'd certainly use `do` when there _is_ a monad, but you happen to not sequence multiple actions. In [yeamer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yeamer-0.1.2.0/docs/Presentation-Yeamer.html) this happens a lot.

Comment: There **is** a `(Monoid a, Monoid b) => Monad ((,,) a b)` instance [since base 4.14](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad) (it's the same as the normal pair/writer monad, just with two monoidal logs instead of one). So the OP's example would work even if `do` always added a `Monad` constraint. I would still call it poor style though, since it's not actually using any monadic features of the `(,,) a b` type, it's just abusing `let` statements in `do` blocks to avoid writing `in`... which isn't even shorter!!

Answer (score 2):

One important thing to know about do-notation is that its rules are applied before type checking. Those rules are (roughly):

- `do { x; y }` ==> `x >> do { y }` (with rules applied recursively)
- `do {x <- a; b }` ==> `a >>= \x -> do { b }`
- `do {{pat} <- a; b }` ==>

  ```hs
  a >>= \x -> case x of 
    {pat} -> do { b }
    _     -> fail "Pattern match fail"`
  ```
- `do { let {decls}; b }` ==> `let {decls} in do { b }`
- `do { a }` ==> `a`

those last two rules are the important ones here - any expression on its own which has no (implicit) semicolons will just become itself. So as long as you don't make use of the first two rules, you can have expressions of any type in your code, without the need for any monad. Following those rules, your code goes from

```hs
rollDieThreeTimes :: (Die, Die, Die)
rollDieThreeTimes = do
  let s = mkStdGen 0
      (d1, s1) = randomR (1, 6) s
      (d2, s2) = randomR (1, 6) s1
      (d3, _) = randomR (1, 6) s2
  (intToDie d1, intToDie d2, intToDie d3)
```

to

```hs
rollDieThreeTimes :: (Die, Die, Die)
rollDieThreeTimes = 
  let s = mkStdGen 0
      (d1, s1) = randomR (1, 6) s
      (d2, s2) = randomR (1, 6) s1
      (d3, _) = randomR (1, 6) s2
  in (intToDie d1, intToDie d2, intToDie d3)
```

and is *then* type checked.